# customized the UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm in the process to create a simple iPhone application that has the "from" and "to" on top on the table view.  This is similar to the Google map's direction input bar in the iPhone.

What are the best steps to create these non-scrollable input bar? Any help, tips, or recommendation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand clearly your question, but i will try at first make a another view with the controlls in IB and assign it to one IBOutlet in UITableViewController class, next assign it to the table view header of the table view.

Here is a good example of it: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

i hope it helps